# Вывод названия выбранной категории laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mvc

Ребят подскажите как работает принцип вывода названия категории. Делал так, неполучилось, возможно неправильную таблицу создал в БД.

```
public function catalog_page($id)
{   
    $menus = Menu::all();
    $category = Menu::with('children')->find($id);

    return view('catalog_page', compact('menus','category'));
}
```

Menu - это модель, таблица, в которой такие поля - id, title, url, images

```
  //Вьюха
  <div class="content__right">
    <h1>{{$category->title}}</h1>
  </div>
```

dd($id); - выдает url выбранной категории.

```
  // Роут
  Route::get('/catalog/{id}', 'SiteController@catalog_page');


  // модель Menu
  namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Menu extends Model
 {
  protected $table = 'menus';
 }
```

Comment: А какие связи `menu` c `children`? `Menu::all()->find($id)` запрос не верный.

Comment: Связи нет, может вы знаете как правильно будет вывести заголовок?

Comment: Если вы пишете `Menu::with('children')` значит в моделе должна быть описана связь. Приведите код моделей, роут также, было бы не плохо.

Comment: Route::get('/catalog/{id}', 'SiteController@catalog_page');

Comment: class Menu extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'menus';
}

Comment: Тут ничего замудренного, возможно при таком подходе я не правильно создал таблицу, просто нет понимания как такое реализовать подругому, может у вас есть альтернативные варианты вывода загаловка не используя children

Comment: Обновите вопрос, добавив из комментариев роут и модель. Прикрепите миграции. И объясните кто такие чилдрены?)

Comment: Обновил, вот только не понимаю зачем прикреплять миграции, они ведь просто создают таблицу, как выглядит таблица я написал

Comment: Логика такая, с роута передаю id выбранной категории в контроллер, а вот как вытащить титл этой выбранной категории иcходя из переданного id я пока не знаю...

Comment: Для того, чтобы понять кто такие `чилдрены` и чем отличаются **$menus** от **$category**. Понять причину по которой вы делаете дважды запрос в одну и ту же таблицу.

Comment: ДА не надо понимать, я просто спросил как правильно сделать, чилдрен это пример из гугла не удачный, в базе одна таблица menus у которой есть поле title, так вот нужно вывести этот title во вьюху

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первые этапы в подавляющем большинстве проектов на Laravel - это создать миграции, определиться со связями моделей и описать их, заполнить БД фейковыми данными (seed), определиться с маршрутами, создать контроллеры и только после этого переходить к выводу в шаблоны.

> Нет необходимости создавать роут (маршрут) под вывод меню.

Представим, что у нас есть маршрут к странице категории с выводом информации о ней:

```
Route::get('/catalog/{id}', 'SiteController@catalog')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

В конструкторе контроллера извлекаем все меню:

```
protected $menus;

public function __construct()
{
  // Теперь коллекция всех менюшек
  // будет доступна из любого метода.
  $this->menus = Menu::all();
}

public function catalog($id)
{
  // Извлекаем текущую категорию из коллекции.
  // Из коллекции, не из БД!!!
  $category = $this->menus->find($id);

  // Распечатаем для наглядности.
  dump($category);

  // Если категории нет в коллекции, то выдаём 404.
  if(is_null($category)) {
    abort(404, 'Page not found');
  }

  return view('catalog', [
      'menus' => $this->menus,
      'category' => $category
    ]);
}
```

Теперь можно вывести текущую категорию и создать меню со всеми категориями в шаблоне:

```
{{-- catalog.blade.php --}}
<main class="main">
  <h1>{{ $category->title }}</h1>
</main>

<aside class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    @foreach ($menus as $item)
      <li>{{ $item->title }}</li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
</aside>
```

Comment: in RouteCollection.php line 179 выдает такую ошибку

Comment: Задал новый вопрос